# document or project criteria needed to use JSON Diff?

Tags: json

JSON Diff is used when we run web projects that use API features. Does this JSON Diff not work on projects that don't use the API feature? Are there any special criteria?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

yes, we're using JSONDiff for find a differences between 2 file code.

The following criteria for use JSON Diff:

1. The project using API feature.
2. Want to do compare 2 file with a file format JSON.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).